# Curve_Edwards25519 in Crypto.PubKey.ECIES

Tags: haskell, cryptography, elliptic-curve

I am trying to use  [this](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/cryptonite-0.25/docs/Crypto-PubKey-ECIES.html) library, when i use `Curve_X25519` form [this](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/cryptonite-0.21/docs/Crypto-ECC.html)  it works fine.

Here is my code

```
import Crypto.PubKey.ECIES
import Crypto.ECC
import Crypto.Error
import Crypto.PubKey.Curve25519
import Data.Proxy
import Data.ByteString.Char8


curve = Proxy :: Proxy Curve_X25519

randomString = "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"

randomSeed = Data.ByteString.Char8.pack randomString


receiversSK = Crypto.PubKey.Curve25519.secretKey randomSeed
receiversPK = Crypto.PubKey.Curve25519.toPublic (throwCryptoError receiversSK)


deriveEncrypt curve receiversPK
```

but when i use `Curve_Edwards25519` from same library

here is my code

```
import Crypto.PubKey.ECIES
import Crypto.ECC
import Crypto.Error
import Crypto.PubKey.Ed25519
import Data.Proxy
import Data.ByteString.Char8


curve = Proxy :: Proxy Curve_Edwards25519

randomString = "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"

randomSeed = Data.ByteString.Char8.pack randomString


receiversSK = Crypto.PubKey.Ed25519.secretKey randomSeed
receiversPK = Crypto.PubKey.Ed25519.toPublic (throwCryptoError receiversSK)


deriveEncrypt curve receiversPK
```

it gives an error in ghci

```
<interactive>:21:21: error:
    • Couldn't match type ‘PublicKey’
                     with ‘Crypto.ECC.Edwards25519.Point’
      Expected type: Point Curve_Edwards25519
        Actual type: PublicKey
    • In the second argument of ‘deriveEncrypt’, namely ‘receiversPK’
      In the expression: deriveEncrypt curve receiversPK
      In an equation for ‘it’: it = deriveEncrypt curve receiversPK
```

can someone help out how to convert `PublicKey` to `Crypto.ECC.Edwards25519.Point`

Comment: `Point` is a type family and the instance for `Curve_Edwards25519` is [here](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/cryptonite-0.25/docs/src/Crypto-ECC.html#line-240). [This](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/cryptonite-0.25/docs/Crypto-ECC-Edwards25519.html#t:Point) is the type you use as the public key.